# menu item width in css only navigation

Tags: html, css

Im trying to build a multi level navigation bar but am stuck on the width of sub menus.
How can I make it so sub menus have a width of at least! its parent item width, but also allow it to grow to the width of the widest item in its list.
All items in a sub menu should have the same width. I dont want the wrapping I seem to have at the moment.

See below code for what Im currently working with. Ignore the colours, they are just there so I could see changes while trying to change things.

I want to keep this css only, so no javascript please, and I dont want to hard code any width values as the menu will be dynamically populated with values I dont know for sure yet. :)

thanks in advance!

```css
.nav{
 background-color:#d6336c;
}
.nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.nav ul li{
 padding:2px 10px;
 float: left;
 position:relative;
 background: #1bc2a2;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav ul li ul{
 display:none;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.nav ul li:hover > ul{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 background-color:orange;
}
.nav ul ul ul{
 left:100%;
 top:0;
}

.nav a{
 color:#ffffff;
}
ul,li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">first</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">second</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">sub1 first</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub1 second</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">sub2 first</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">sub2 second</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">sub3 first</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">sub3 second</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">sub3 third</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
     <li><a href="#">sub2 third</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">third</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">.</a>
     <li><a href="#">.</a>
     <li><a href="#">.</a>
    </ul>
   </li>
  <li><a href="#">fourth</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">fifth</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min-width: 100%` on the nested menus will make sure the menu is at least as wide as the parent `li`, and `white-space: nowrap` on the `li`'s will expand the width of the menu for longer text in the `li`'s

```css
.nav {
  background-color: #d6336c;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: #1bc2a2;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
}

.nav ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.nav a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">first</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">second</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sub1 first</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub1 second</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub2 first</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub2 second</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub3 first</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub3 second</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub3 third</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">sub2 third</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">third</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">fourth</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">fifth</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what _not_ should happen if I got the questioner right. The sub menu should be on one line, no wrapping is wanted.

Comment: @Psi the sub menu text isn't wrapping for me. That's what `white-space: nowrap` does. Is it wrapping for you?

Comment: No, but the menu items are. What I understood is, that he wants them all on the same line as they are in the first level.

Comment: @Psi oh I thought you were OP! I don't think OP wants all of the menu items to be displayed inline - pretty sure they just don't want the words *within* each item to wrap.

Comment: Ah, maybe yes, can also be understood that way.

Comment: @MichaelCoker thank you, thats what I meant/needed. I have updated my question with your solutions. I also added a sub menu under item "third" where the items are smaller, its not working out as expected. They should be below each other, but have the length of the parent item ("third"). Also, how can I make the items actually stretch all the way, I mean, so the green background actually covers the whole orange, per item.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Perfect! and finally, do I have any excessive/redundant or useless code in there? such as position, display etc that arent needed? Basically, can it be cleaned up a bit or is it ok?

Comment: @FrankUnderwood that's a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MichaelCoker Didnt know about that one, will post first thing in the morning. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the key is going to be `white-space: nowrap`, with a couple extra styles to keep the right spacing. This is what was added to the snippet below:

```
.nav ul.dropdown li {
  /* change to allow full width */
    padding:2px 0 2px 10px;

  /* prevent breaking word to new line */
  white-space: nowrap;

  /* make green color extend */
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.nav{
 background-color:#d6336c;
}
.nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.nav ul li{
  padding: 2px 10px; 
 float: left;
 position:relative;
 background: #1bc2a2;
}

.nav ul li ul{
 display:none;
}
.nav ul li:hover > ul{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 background-color:orange;
}
.nav ul ul ul{
 left:100%;
 top:0;
}

.nav ul.dropdown li {
  /* change to allow full width */
 padding:2px 0 2px 10px;
    
  /* prevent breaking word to new line */
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  /* make green color extend */
  min-width: 100%;
}

.nav a{
 color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">first</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">second</a>
   <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">sub1 first</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub1 second</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
     <li><a href="#">sub2 first</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">sub2 second</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
       <li><a href="#">sub3 first</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">sub3 second</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">sub3 third</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
     <li><a href="#">sub2 third</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">third</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">fourth</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">fifth</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. The nowrap thing fixed the line break issue, but the green colour doesnt extend in your example for me. Firefox 49. Also, I have added a follow up question in the similar answer by Michael Coker.